# How to use APIGuard with Fractal Transformer in Laravel?

Tags: php, web-services, api, laravel, transformer-model

I'm trying to create a web API in Laravel.
I'm using the following packages for me to manage the REST return: [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), spatie/fractal and also [ApiGuard](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard).

My controller has the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\Http\Controllers\ApiGuardController;
use App\CSV;
use App\CSVTransformer;

class ApiController extends ApiGuardController
{
    public function info()
    {
        $csvs = CSV::all();
        $estado = [0,0,0,0];

        foreach ($csvs as $csv) {
            switch ($csv->estado) {
                case "Renovado":
                    $estado[0]++;
                    break;
                case "Expirado":
                    $estado[1]++;
                    break;
                case "Aguardar Pagamento":
                    $estado[2]++;
                    break;
                case "Não Renovado":
                    $estado[3]++;
                    break;
            }
        }            

        return $this->response->withCollection($csvs, new CSVTransformer);
    }

    public function renovacoes() {
        $csvs = CSV::all();

        return json_encode([ "data" => $csvs ]);
    }
}
```

This is what the transformer looks like:

```
namespace App;

use App\CSV;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class CSVTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(CSV $csv)
    {
        return [
            'id'      => (int) $csv->id,
            'renovacao'   => $csv->renovacao
        ];
    }
}
```

The problem is, when accessing the chosen POST route to get the JSON return, the following error is thrown:

```
Class 'League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract' not found.
```

How do I solve this, so that my transformer works as it is supposed to?

EDIT:

Also, here's the `CSV` class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class CSV extends Model
{
    protected $table = "csv";
}
```

Routes file:

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ["apiguard"]], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
            Route::post("/renovations/info","ApiController@info");

            Route::post("/renovations","ApiController@renovacoes");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show your `CSV` class as well? Currently I cannot see why the `TransformerAbstract` class cannot be loaded. Your namespaces and `use`s seem to be correct.

Comment: It works out-of-the-box with my installation. Fractal and ApiGuard installed via composer, made the required migrations via `php artisan migrate`, set up the files according to yours (ApiController, CSVTransformator, etc...) , adjusted `routes.php` - so far so good! Now I need to know whats inside your `CSV` class..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added it to the post.

Comment: Works quite well. I get a valid JSON response `{"error":{"code":"GEN-UNAUTHORIZED","http_code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}}`. Can you show your `route.php` and the complete error message with stack trace?

Comment: The section of the routes that has to do with this is posted. The full error is: 'FatalErrorException: Class League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract not found (CSVTransformer.php line 9)'

Comment: Did you install `Fractal`via composer `composer require league/fractal`? You can also do a `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloading classes

Comment: Yes, I did. Btw, just going through the files again, I found out that, in the vendor folder of league/fractal, there isn't a TransformerAbstract.php file. Isn't that supposed to come when I use the composer require command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vendor/league` folder should look like this:

```
fractal
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── composer.json
    └── src
        ├── Manager.php
        ├── Pagination
        ├── ParamBag.php
        ├── Resource
        ├── Scope.php
        ├── Serializer
        └── TransformerAbstract.php
```

There is a `TransformerAbstract.php` with this content:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the League\Fractal package.
 *
 * (c) Phil Sturgeon <me@philsturgeon.uk>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace League\Fractal;

use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Item;
use League\Fractal\Resource\NullResource;
use League\Fractal\Resource\ResourceAbstract;

/**
 * Transformer Abstract
 *
 * All Transformer classes should extend this to utilize the convenience methods
 * collection() and item(), and make the self::$availableIncludes property available.
 * Extend it and add a `transform()` method to transform any default or included data
 * into a basic array.
 */
abstract class TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * Resources that can be included if requested.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableIncludes = [];

    /**
     * Include resources without needing it to be requested.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $defaultIncludes = [];

    /**
     * The transformer should know about the current scope, so we can fetch relevant params.
     *
     * @var Scope
     */
    protected $currentScope;

    /**
     * Getter for availableIncludes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAvailableIncludes()
    {
        return $this->availableIncludes;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for defaultIncludes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaultIncludes()
    {
        return $this->defaultIncludes;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for currentScope.
     *
     * @return \League\Fractal\Scope
     */
    public function getCurrentScope()
    {
        return $this->currentScope;
    }

    /**
     * Figure out which includes we need.
     *
     * @internal
     *
     * @param Scope $scope
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function figureOutWhichIncludes(Scope $scope)
    {
        $includes = $this->getDefaultIncludes();
        foreach ($this->getAvailableIncludes() as $include) {
            if ($scope->isRequested($include)) {
                $includes[] = $include;
            }
        }

        return $includes;
    }

    /**
     * This method is fired to loop through available includes, see if any of
     * them are requested and permitted for this scope.
     *
     * @internal
     *
     * @param Scope $scope
     * @param mixed $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function processIncludedResources(Scope $scope, $data)
    {
        $includedData = [];

        $includes = $this->figureOutWhichIncludes($scope);

        foreach ($includes as $include) {
            $includedData = $this->includeResourceIfAvailable(
                $scope,
                $data,
                $includedData,
                $include
            );
        }

        return $includedData === [] ? false : $includedData;
    }

    /**
     * Include a resource only if it is available on the method.
     *
     * @internal
     *
     * @param Scope  $scope
     * @param mixed  $data
     * @param array  $includedData
     * @param string $include
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function includeResourceIfAvailable(
        Scope $scope,
        $data,
        $includedData,
        $include
    ) {
        if ($resource = $this->callIncludeMethod($scope, $include, $data)) {
            $childScope = $scope->embedChildScope($include, $resource);

            $includedData[$include] = $childScope->toArray();
        }

        return $includedData;
    }

    /**
     * Call Include Method.
     *
     * @internal
     *
     * @param Scope  $scope
     * @param string $includeName
     * @param mixed  $data
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     *
     * @return \League\Fractal\Resource\ResourceInterface
     */
    protected function callIncludeMethod(Scope $scope, $includeName, $data)
    {
        $scopeIdentifier = $scope->getIdentifier($includeName);
        $params = $scope->getManager()->getIncludeParams($scopeIdentifier);

        // Check if the method name actually exists
        $methodName = 'include'.str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('-', ' ', $includeName))));

        $resource = call_user_func([$this, $methodName], $data, $params);

        if ($resource === null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! $resource instanceof ResourceAbstract) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf(
                'Invalid return value from %s::%s(). Expected %s, received %s.',
                __CLASS__,
                $methodName,
                'League\Fractal\Resource\ResourceAbstract',
                gettype($resource)
            ));
        }

        return $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for availableIncludes.
     *
     * @param array $availableIncludes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAvailableIncludes($availableIncludes)
    {
        $this->availableIncludes = $availableIncludes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for defaultIncludes.
     *
     * @param array $defaultIncludes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDefaultIncludes($defaultIncludes)
    {
        $this->defaultIncludes = $defaultIncludes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for currentScope.
     *
     * @param Scope $currentScope
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCurrentScope($currentScope)
    {
        $this->currentScope = $currentScope;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new item resource object.
     *
     * @param mixed                        $data
     * @param TransformerAbstract|callable $transformer
     * @param string                       $resourceKey
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    protected function item($data, $transformer, $resourceKey = null)
    {
        return new Item($data, $transformer, $resourceKey);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new collection resource object.
     *
     * @param mixed                        $data
     * @param TransformerAbstract|callable $transformer
     * @param string                       $resourceKey
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    protected function collection($data, $transformer, $resourceKey = null)
    {
        return new Collection($data, $transformer, $resourceKey);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new null resource object.
     *
     * @return NullResource
     */
    protected function null()
    {
        return new NullResource();
    }
}
```

Maybe you should reinstall the `fractal` package.

Reinstall the package:

- Remove the old one `composer remove league/fractal`
- Optional: Update composer with the latest package versions `composer update`
- Install fractal `composer require league/fractal`

Comment: Ok, tried to create this file manually and the error changed, now it's another file, so I really should reinstall the package. How do I do that? Isn't 'composer require league/fractal' enough?

Comment: Normally that should be enough. I updated my post with the reinstallation.

Comment: Thank you so much! The package didn't seem to update correctly w/ just the commands, so I had to manually delete the fractal folder, after the 2 first steps, and then running the last step. It's now working :D

Comment: Glad I could help :) If you like, you can also upvote my answer.